# how can i select the 3,5 and 7th item with nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 

I want to select the 3rd , 5th and 7th items with nth-child

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
element_name:nth-child(3),element_name:nth-child(5), element_name:nth-child(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        h:nth-child(3) {
            background-color: red;
            color: blue;
        }

        h:nth-child(5) {
            background-color: blue;
            color: azure;
        }

        h:nth-child(7) {
            background-color: forestgreen;
            color: #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h>heading1</h>
    <h>heading2</h>
    <h>heading3</h>
    <h>heading4</h>
    <h>heading5</h>
    <h>heading6</h>
    <h>heading7</h>
    <h>heading8</h>

</body>

</html>
```